# What do I need to change in the code so that I can save the current image?

Tags: html, css

When I right-click on the carousel image and click "save", the downloaded image is the one before the current one. What do I need to change in the code to be able to save the current image? It seems so simple, but I can't figure out what it is.

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST1">
    </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST2">
    </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST3">
    </div>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I be wrong with a question? Anyway, now that the mysterious nonsequiter comment has been deleted, I see we have an answer.

Comment: I had replied to another user, he deleted it and my answer was out of context. It was then that I deleted my reply. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `position: static` to `position: relative` in `.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item` seems to fix it:

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST1">
    </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST2">
    </div>
    <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/2000x800/F90/fff/?text=TEST3">
    </div>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control next control-1">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-control prev control-2">‹</label>
    <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-control next control-2">›</label>
    <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-control prev control-3">‹</label>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet">•</label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```